# MySQL Stop a user from deleting an entire table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains millions of records in MySQL.
Is there a way to prevent users from **accidentally executing** "delete from table1;" and only allow them to delete records by executing this query "delete from table1 where id=10;"

Currently the user privilege is "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON `db1`.`table1` TO 'user'@'localhost'".

Thanks.

Comment: You must have to use the roles to counter this situation. On the base of roles, you must specify which role can remove the record. i-e admin or user . Don't allow the user to execute query in case of user.

Comment: Use 2 different server. One for `production` and one for `development`. Do all your development queries on `development`. Deploy only tested queries to `production`. Other solution might be create `TRIGGER BEFORE DELETE` to each table, and inside this trigger, insert into `backup_table` for deleted row.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a *server* mode called [*sql_safe_updates*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates).  Despite the name, it applies to both updates and deletes.

When this mode is enabled, users need to provide a `key` in the `where` clause or `limit` for `update` and `delete`.

This can also be set in the MySQL client.